# Как получать неповторяющиеся случайные числа?

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Нужно, чтобы rand выводила одно число один раз в php, то есть чтобы числа не повторялись. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я знаю как воспроизвести. Если не rand то скажите пожалуйста такую функцию который выбирает случайную цифру, и при этом цифры не повторяются.

Comment: эмммм.... да как бы числа и не должны повторяться... см пример здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php

Comment: echo rand(5, 15); но в этом примере цифры повторяются.

Comment: такая была проблема в последний раз только на МК-61 ))))

Answer (score 3):

Хм...

```
<?php
//от 1 до ста случайные числа, выведем 50;
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) $m[]=$i;
shuffle($m);
for ($i=1;$i<=50;$i++) echo array_pop($m)."\n";
```

http://ideone.com/0V0eST

---

http://ideone.com/0V0eST

если $start далеко от $end:

```
<?php
//от 1 до 100000000 случайные числа, выведем 50;
$length=50;
$start=1;
$end=100000000;
$array=array();
while (count($array)<$length) {
    $array[mt_rand($start,$end)]="";
}
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Comment: @eicto как всегда рулит!

Answer (score 0):

пишите сгенерированные числа в массив, и при генерации нового числа сравнивайте с теми что уже лежат в массиве, если есть то генерим заново.. если числа нет в массиве записываем его туда..

поправка, если требуется перезагрузка страницы.. пишите в базу/куки/сессию или файл

Comment: <?php
session_start();
$i = 1;
$iq = 16;
if(!empty($i) and !empty($iq)){
$n = rand($i,$iq);
$_SESSION['a'][] = $n;
if($n == $_SESSION['a'][count($_SESSION['a'])-2])
$q = rand($i,$iq);
$q = $n;
}

echo $n;
?> 
Я так написал но не работает, каждый раз когда обновляю страницу не повторяется генерирование

Comment: не вводите излишнюю сессионную переменную, я вас прошу!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте очистить кеш браузера.

Comment: Нет это не помогает, я в верху в комментариях выложил код который я написал,в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать range дальше array_unique и array_shuffle но это только если один раз такое делать:)